# Android : I have an existing layout with textview...can i change the content dynamically in activity

Tags: android, textview

I know how to create text views dynamically, but i want to change the data of an existing view dynamically and display it. is there a way to do it?

Comment: Q: "Is there any..." - A: "Yes, there is."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do? Do you really want to dynamically change the text in your TextView objects when the user enter data? You can certainly do that, if you have a reason, but, if the text is static, it is usually set in the main.xml file, like this:

```
<TextView  
android:id="@+id/text"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/text"/>
```

The string "@string/text" refers to an entry in your strings.xml file that looks like this:

```
<string name="text">Any string</string>
```

If you really want to change this text later you'd get a reference to the TextView by utilizing the id defined for it within main.xml, like this:

```
final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
textViewToChange.setText(
     "The new text that I'd like to display now that the user has entered");
```

Comment: I'm completely new to android. Thank you dude. Its working.

Comment: your always welcome:)  Even I was new to android once it was stackoverflow that gave me the start :)